# Includes causing problems in c++. How to learn to do c++ right

Tags: c++

So I have made a complex project and now I have too many include files causing me headaches. How can I best manage these classes? Some classes need to use other classes. I also have a .h file containing a bunch of arrays of int. These stay the same through the application but I get the problem when the compiler complains that I am redefining the array.

Should I make a class library? Namespace? DLL? What is the best practice and where can I find out how to do the right one?

Comment: http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources

Comment: The solution to your problem may involve changing to a nomenclature that is unlikely to conflict.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in all your headers.

> **file.h**
>
> ```
>    #ifndef FILE_H_INCLUDED
>    #define FILE_H_INCLUDED
>
>    void foo();
>
>    #endif
> ```

- Avoid global variables when possible. If you must use them, declare global variables using `extern` and place the definition in a `.cpp` file instead.

> **file.h**
>
> ```
>    extern int var[20];
> ```
>
> **file.cpp**
>
> ```
>    int var[20];
> ```

- When possible, use forward declarations. You can use forward declarations whenever you use only a reference or a pointer to a class and don't dereference that pointer.

> **useful.h**
>
> ```
>    class Useful {};
> ```
>
> **other.h**
>
> ```
>    // Forward-declare instead of #include
>    class Useful;
>
>    class Other
>    {
>        Useful* helper;
>    };
> ```

Comment: This sounds great to me. How does the compiler know about FILE_H_INCLUDED

Comment: @JonathanO: Because you just `#define`d it inside the `#ifndef`.

Comment: You're misuderstanding. The `#define` is to prevent the compiler from parsing the definition of whatever is inside of the `#ifndef` block twice. Parsing it twice is why you're likely gewtting errors about it being defined twice. Keep in mind that including a file just takes the contents of the file and processes it at the point of the include. If you include a file twice, it is processed twice, and everything in it is defined twice. So yes, it works for preventing multiple definition of everyhting you put inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there really is a best practice, it depends on the situation. Something I might recommend is to group like objects into a namespace then put all of the definitions in a single .h file. If the implementations are short, put them all in a single cpp file. Here at my work we have a database access layer like this. There are roughly a couple dozen objects that are populated by stored procs. The code is still a major pain in the ass but it's better than having two dozen .h and cpp files that are all less than 500 lines. If you do this comments to compartmentalize object definitions become really important. You can easily get files longer than 10,000 lines so you need something to break them up.

Of course use include guards, they'll likely solve the redefining error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the difference between a definition and a declaration, and what uses of an entity required the entity to be declared. Then you also need to learn the 'one definition rule' (ODR) which tells you when when you're not allowed to have more than one definition in the program (and therefore the definition can't go in a header) and what things can be defined more than once as long as the definitions are identical (and therefore the definition can go in a header).

For example, those arrays you're declaring; since these are globally visible arrays the program can only contain one definition, and therefore the definition can't go in a header. Every part of the program that needs to access them simply needs to know their declaration. So instead of putting a definition in a header file and violating the ODR, you should have a C++ file that contains their definition and a header that contains declarations for them.

Code like this:

```
int foo[100];
```

both declares and defines the array `foo`. Put code like this in a C++ file. To only *declare* this array you do this:

```
extern int foo[100];
```

Put code like this in a header.

Class definitions, inline functions, and templates are all things that can be defined multiple times as long as the definitions are identical. You can put these definitions into headers, whereas regular functions, and global variables may only be defined once, so you declare them in headers and then define them in implementation files.